Get list of forms user has access to via user ID or group they're in
I have some tables like so:
users

id        | name
-----------------------
1           Ben
2           Josh

groups

id        | name
-----------------------
1           Group 1
2           Group 2

group_users

id        | group_id       | user_id
------------------------------------
1           1                1

forms

id        | name
-----------------------
1           Contact Us
2           Questions

form_access

id        | form_id         | user_id        | group_id
-------------------------------------------------------
1           1                 1                null
2           2                 null             1

Essentially, access to a form can be given to an entire group or a user individually. I'm looking for the most efficient way to get all the forms a user has access to. Right now, I'm using Supabase with Postgres and I thought creating a view might be the best way to go (supabase-js client isn't too flexible on queries like this so I needed a view):
SELECT
  form_access.user_id,
  group_users.user_id as group_user_id,
  forms.*
FROM
  forms
  INNER JOIN form_access ON form_access.form_id = forms.id
  LEFT JOIN group_users ON group_users.group_id = form_access.group_id

And from there, I can query where a user_id or group_user_id is the authenticated user. I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this or a better approach though and hoping for some feedback. Additionally, I'll need to paginate this data and also, given a form_id, ensure the user has access to a particular form.

I think you are right on track. But doing a full outer join with group_users might slow things down.
Try using UNION ALL to combine two queries.
One that selects forms directly granted to the user (using form_access.user_id is not null).
Another that selects forms granted to the user's groups (using group_users.user_id and form_access.group_id).
The view definition for this will look something like this;
 CREATE VIEW user_accessible_forms AS
    SELECT form_access.user_id, null as group_user_id, forms.*
    FROM forms
    INNER JOIN form_access ON form_access.form_id = forms.id
    WHERE form_access.user_id IS NOT NULL
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT form_access.user_id, group_users.user_id as group_user_id, forms.*
    FROM forms
    INNER JOIN form_access ON form_access.form_id = forms.id
    INNER JOIN group_users ON group_users.group_id = form_access.group_id;

To get all forms a specific user (e.g., user ID 1) can access:
SELECT * FROM user_accessible_forms WHERE user_id = 1;

This will return all forms Ben (user ID 1) has access to, including those directly granted and those through his group membership.
You can add a LIMIT and OFFSET clause to the above query to paginate.
SELECT * FROM user_accessible_forms WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20;

This retrieves the next 10 forms after skipping the first 20 results.
Checking if a user has access to a particular form (e.g., form ID 2):
SELECT 1 FROM user_accessible_forms 
WHERE user_id = 1 AND (form_id = 2 OR group_user_id = 1);

This query checks if either the user has direct access (form_id = 2) or belongs to a group with access (group_user_id = 1). It returns 1 if access is granted, otherwise it returns nothing.
Did this work?
